# Emailing Script Return

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for the code required to email myself the return I receive when performing PowerShell scripts. I know I'd have to use a `Send-MailMessage`, but I'm stuck with the PowerShell to use the return I receive as the email body.

My powershell script is a mixture of powershell and sqlcmd.

For example:

```
echo "Selecting Count from ExampleTable"
sqlcmd -i D:\IRDW\Tools\script_to_Count_ExampleTable.txt
Start-Sleep 2
```

Return in powershell:

```
124794

(1 rows affected)
```

Comment: `$output = sqlcmd ... | Out-String; Send-MailMessage ... -Body $output ...`

Comment: @ansgarWiechers My powershell script is a mixture of powershell and sqlcmd - So I'm not sure that this would work?

Comment: `$output = C:\path\to\your.ps1 | Out-String; Send-MailMessage ... -Body $output ...`

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion:

```
$body = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    echo 'test'
    'sqlcmd ...'
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
} | Out-String
```

or

```
$body = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    echo 'test'
    'sqlcmd ...'
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
} | Wait-Job | Receive-Job | Out-String
```